# FLASK RUN still working despite the FLASK_APP file specified being renamed

Tags: python, flask

I am following a tutorial on FLASK.   Initially the routes were defined in a root file called "flaskblog.py".  I had to set the FLASK_APP variable to "flaskblog.py" in order for "flask run" to work.

Later in the tutorial, the project was restructured into packages, and the "flaskblog.py" file renamed to "run.py".  A folder (i.e. package) was created called "flaskblog".

To my surprise, "flask run" still worked, and even seems to flag it is using "flaskblog.py"...but this doesn't exist any more.

Folder structure:

```
(base) C:\flask_blog>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume OSDisk
Volume serial number is 36E9-84F4
C:.
│   run.py
│   site.db
│
├───.vscode
│       launch.json
│
├───flaskblog
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   routes.py
│   │   site.db
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───static
│   │       main.css
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │       about.html
│   │       css.html
│   │       home.html
│   │       layout.html
│   │       layout_plain.html
│   │       login.html
│   │       register.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           forms.cpython-37.pyc
│           models.cpython-37.pyc
│           routes.cpython-37.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│
└───__pycache__
        app.cpython-37.pyc
        flaskblog.cpython-37.pyc
        forms.cpython-37.pyc
        models.cpython-37.pyc
```

Note the absence of "flaskblog.py".

See what I get when I use "flask run":

```
(ariel) C:\flask_blog>SET FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py

(ariel) C:\flask_blog>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "flaskblog.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

run.py is simply:

```
from flaskblog import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

effectively this only gets called if I want to start the app using "python run.py", and not "flask run".

Answer (score 0):

You set the Flask App name as flaskblog.py using the command

```
SET FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py
```

If you reset it, it will have new name

Comment: There isnt a flaskblog.py file, so the whole thing should collapse.   I think it may be using the module rather than complaining there is no flaskblog.py file present.  The run.py file "used" to be called "flaskblog.py" before we re-organised into a package.

Comment: There is pyc file created. It refers to that

Comment: That doesnt reflect my current working set of files though, how can I flush this out? Or is the pyc file coming from the new module we created called "flaskblog"?  Or is it an artefact of the old project structure?

Comment: It seems windows issue. I tried on linux and could not replicate issue. I got error Error: Could not import "flaskblog".
Have you tried on another terminal ?
Also would you be able to share run.py ?

Comment: updated main question with run.py.  The message you receive is exactly what I was expecting to receive, seeing as flaskblog.py doesn't exist

Comment: did you set FLASK_DEBUG=1 in the environment?

Comment: Not for this terminal session

Comment: Where is the app module mentioned in run.py ?

Comment: the run.py is only relevant if I run using "python run.py".  I am running using "flask run", which should drive it to load flaskblog.py (FLAS_APP variable).  And somehow it does (!) despite the file note existing.  I can only assume it uses the "flaskblog" module instead.  Although this is not evident from the debug output which clearly states "flaskblog.py" is used.

Comment: You can tell Flask not to load dotenv files even when python-dotenv is installed by setting the FLASK_SKIP_DOTENV environment variable. This can be useful if you want to load them manually, or if you’re using a project runner that loads them already. Keep in mind that the environment variables must be set before the app loads or it won’t configure as expected.

$ export FLASK_SKIP_DOTENV=1
$ flask run

Comment: Thanks, although not sure where dot net comes into this?

Comment: I don't even have a .env file in my project?